# Distributing to client via IPA with UDIDs?

Tags: ios, xcode, beta

A client is asking me to send an IPA file to them.

"You can send the file via email and it can be installed as a developer device"

I tested creating an IPA file for the project and archived it allowing XCode to automatically manage signing. This, as expected, only has my one device's UDID stored in the IPA.

I've gone into the apple developer portal and created an Ad-Hoc provisioning profile for this app. I am not seeing how to add in devices to the profile. When I go to edit the profile, the devices only show the option to select iPhone, Mac, or both.

I'm using Testflight, but the client also wants the IPA.

How can I correctly create an IPA file of my project with the provided device UDIDs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log into your apple account and go inside "Certificates, IDs and Profiles" section. There you'll see a section named "Devices", select the option "All" under it. Now you'll see + button top right corner, press it and add the udid of your client and name that device whatever you want and press continue.
Now open your xcode,

[image]

press the small i button in front of provisioning profile and drag and drop your provisioning profile (circled in black) anywhere on your desktop. Check the name of your provisioning profile and now go to Library / MobileDevice / ProvisioningProfiles. There you'll see all your provisioning profiles. Now just delete the one that has same name as the one that you just dropped on the desktop. After that Xcode will automatically generate the new provisioning profile for you with all the newly added udids inside it. Now you can archieve your project and generate the ipa file. It will now run on your client's device.
P.S. instead of doing all this you can also generate a new provisioning profile from your apple account and double click on it to insert it into xcode.